# Manage personal certificates in multi account Android tablet

Tags: android, certificate, multi-user

I have a Samsumg Galaxy Tab 2 which runs Android 4.2 but Samsumg's rom removed multi user feature. So, as I can not test this feature, I´d like to ask some questions about it:

- Is it possible create several users and set a different pin code (or pattern) for each one to unlock the screen (or for switching active user)?

  - When you store a personal certificate (.p12) in your device, if you dont have any security control activated (pin, pattern, whatever), Android enforces you to set it. Does it apply to all users?
  - An user can only use his imported certificates? or they will be available to any user?

My propouse is to have a tablet with multiple users. It should be secured in order one user can only access its account and he can only use its own personal certificate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes It is possible to create different security lock for each user
2. **Only owner (Primary user) can install the Certificates**. Certificates are available to all users. Secondary users can not install certificates.

Hope This Helps!

Comment: Sure, it helped a lot! 
Just one more question, when you install a certificate, is there any way to force to always enter pin certificate?

Comment: Android does not ask to enter PIN always while installing certificate. It just forces to set PIN on device. I think there are some ".pfx" certificate files. If user tries to install certificate using this file, it asks to enter PIN to extract certificates. This pin different than device PIN. I think that PIN is specific to the file. Not sure if this is relevant to your question :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I really didnt explain myself right ;) What I meant is if there is any way to force the user to enter the certificate pin each time he wants to use it (to make a digital signature, for example). As every certificated installed on the device is available to all users, it could be a "security" measure to ensure an user only can use its own certificates.

Comment: I think once certificate is installed device-wide, its available to all. To secure it, you can install the certificate in App's local keystore. It will make sure that the certificate is not available to any other app/user.

Comment: I want to install several certificates to use them in the same application and they must be only accessed by they owners.